# Tag synonym/merge request: hdd -> hard-disk

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I just realised we have both a [hdd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdd) tag and a [hard-drive](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) tag. They both relate to the same thing: a hard disk drive.

- [hard-drive](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) - 88 questions, has a tag wiki
- [hdd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdd) - 37 questions, no tag wiki

**I suggest we make [hdd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdd) a synonym of [hard-drive](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) because:**

a) [hard-drive](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) has more questions and already has a tag wiki

b) 'HDD' is an acronym for 'Hard Disk Drive', or simply a 'hard disk'. We should use the full description for formality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with that.  I've merged `hdd` into `hard-drive`.